# How do I achieve database consistency when rewriting sections of a table?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm, database-locking

I have a simple database relationship: one Item relates to many ItemDetails.  ItemDetails are updated all at once: a message comes in via HTTP POST with the full set of ItemDetails to replace any old ItemDetails with.  The logic I use is this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    ...
    ItemDetails.objects.filter(item_id=item_id).all().delete()
    for item in new_item_list:
        ItemDetails.objects.create(title=item.title, ...)
```

But this seems to have a race condition if two senders send an update at the same time.  I sometimes see duplicated lists, since (I think) the delete() is running on two threads in more or less parallel and then the creates happen.

What locking strategy can I use to avoid this problem?  I am using Django with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do you know about `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? You should lock the parent item, make the update and commit the transaction.

Comment: I did not but I do now and that looks perfect.  Write it as an answer and I'll accept after testing it.

Comment: I'm in no urgent need of the points. If you've got time feel free to write your own and accept it - it will better explain the motivation+solution anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the question comments, one Django/Postgres solution is to use `select_for_update()` on the proper `Item` row before messing with the children.  That causes Django to block awaiting the lock.  So changing the logic to the below fixes the race condition:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # Just add this and Django will block here until other threads let go.
    item = Item.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=item_id)
    ...
    ItemDetails.objects.filter(item_id=item_id).all().delete()
    for item in new_item_list:
        ItemDetails.objects.create(title=item.title, ...)
```